# Convergence of complex series that are not absolutely convergent?

Tags: fourier-analysis

Does anyone know of a convergence test for a complex series of the form

$$\sum_n  a_n \cdot \exp(i \cdot b_n)$$

?

The particular series I need to understand has a_n going to zero as n goes to
infinity,  but it  fails the absolute convergence test.   However numerically
I do find it to converge.    It  should have something to do with convergence of Fourier series (since $\ \exp(i\cdot t)\ =\ \cos(t)\,+\,i\cdot \sin(t)$).

Comment: This seems very vague to me. Why don't you describe the particular series?

Comment: I need something stronger than the Dirichlet test,  since my series fails it, but still converges!   Are such examples known?

Comment: Somehow, this got put on hold,  but whoever suggested summation by parts,  thank you!   It did the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your $a_n$s are nonnegative, decrease monotonically, and approach zero, and the $b_n$s are such that $\sum e^{i x b_n}$ remains bounded, then Dirichlet's test would apply here and give you convergence. If the $b_n$'s are an arithmetic sequence, as in the case of Fourier series, then you have the second of these criteria (for $x\neq0$).

Comment: Yoav,  thanks.  But my series fails the Dirichlet test but still converges!   Any ideas?

Comment: I refined the question in my next post.

Comment: Apparently the Dirichlet test is not an "if and only" statement.   My series fails it,  but still converges.  Is that right?